# Wordpress Child Theme CSS enqueue

Tags: css, wordpress

[image]
Thanks for taking the time to read this. I've purchased the Beep theme from themeforest and created a child theme to work from. I've created the functions.php and style.css files in the child directory. When I activate the theme in WP some of the formatting looked messed up. Especially the navigation area. I've tried placing a PHP echo in the functions.php file which is relayed to the site - so WP is definitely finding the functions.php file. I've attached a screenshot of the child CSS, child functions and the my site directory structure. Also included is a screenshot from WP of what the Parent theme homepage looks like and what the Child theme looks like. Antony

![enter image description here][2]

Comment: Kindly go to appearance and check with menu settings, because most of the time theme will take all the categories or pages by default as menu. So change it to you costum menu or of theme custom menu

Comment: Hi Kundan - thank you very much for taking the time to answer. I did as you instructed and it now works :-)

Comment: Kundan - not sure how to mark your answer as ticked for answering my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly go to appearance and check with menu settings, because most of the time theme will take all the categories or pages by default as menu. So change it to you custom menu or of theme custom menu –